# When do semesters/trimesters begin and end for universities in England and France?

Tags: academic-history

I keep trying to find out when classes start and end for English and French universities (specifically, Oxford, Cambridge, and the Sorbonne), but for some reason, I can’t seem to get a direct answer. For instance, on Oxford University’s calendar, it showed Sunday as the beginning of the trimester, but I was looking for the dates the classes/lectures start and end each trimester. I figure it’s the following Monday, but I have no idea. Then I tried looking up how they determine what day classes start for Cambridge, because I got all sorts of random results. Some saying “the 1st of every October” and others saying “the 1st Tuesday of September.” The Sorbonne doesn’t even have any schedules or calendars listed anywhere. Basically, I am trying to find out what the dates for each semester/trimester would have been for those colleges in the years 1991-1992. I need to know because I’m trying to write about this person who audited classes at Oxford for one semester in 1991, then audited classes at Cambridge the next semester in 1991-1992 (it wasn’t specified which year), and then finally finished auditing classes at the Sorbonne for the final semester in 1992, and I’m needing to write the dates on a timeline

Comment: Have you tried emailing the records/admin department or librarian at any of the universities? I expect they could find the records for the term dates you're specifically interested in. The dates change from year to year due to the holidays not always being on the same day (Christmas) or date (Easter).

Comment: It's hard to understand why the actual dates are so important, rather  than just month and year. 1991 is long ago for any memory of it.

Comment: @Buffy. Alright, so what are the months then for each trimester?

Comment: I don't know, but someone might be able to help with those looser constraints. Perhaps you should edit the question.

Comment: BTW, is what you're writing a novel, a biography, or something else?

Comment: @DanielHatton I am writing a novel

Answer (score 4):

## Answer for Cambridge

Cambridge distinguishes between "term" (a period during which accommodation is available to undergraduates and when small-group tutorials ("supervisions") may be scheduled by agreement between students and supervisor) and "full term" (a period within a term, three-quarters of the length of the term, when centrally-scheduled lectures and practical classes take place).

The first *term* of each academic year ("Michaelmas term") does indeed begin on 1st October, and is 80 days long; the second term ("Lent Term") begins on 5th January, and is 80 days long; the third term ("Easter term") begins on either 10th April (in years when Easter full term starts before 22nd April) or 17th April (in years when Easter full term starts on or after 22nd April), and is 70 days long.

The start dates of full terms are determined by a table that appears in [chapter II of the University Ordinances](https://www.admin.cam.ac.uk/univ/so/pdfs/2020/ordinance02.pdf) (which is also where I got the information in the previous paragraph).  The table covers an 11-year period, so any edition of the Statutes and Ordinances between 1982 and 1992 should give you the information you want.  Google Books possesses digitized copies of the 1982, 1984, 1985, and 1989 editions, but only makes them available in "snippet view", so it's a bit tricky to find anything.  However, I've managed it: in the 1991-1992 academic year, Michaelmas full term started on 8th October 1991, Lent full term started on 14th January 1992, and Easter full term started on 21st April 1992.

Comment: Awesome! Thank you. And what dates did the terms/lectures end?

Comment: I also found the Michaelmas term for Oxford in 1991-1992 was October 9-December 19. Is there a way to determine when the full term started or when classes began based on that information?

Comment: @AnthonyFallone The above provides the start date and length of each term and full term; I thought I could leave calculating the end date as an exercise for the reader (don't forget 1992 was a leap year).

Comment: One potential gotcha: although full term always starts on a Tuesday, the centrally-scheduled activities on that first Tuesday and Wednesday are just planning and registration meetings: lectures and practical classes don't start until the Thursday.

Comment: @AnthonyFallone I'm afraid I don't even know whether Oxford _has_ a distinction between "term" and "full term".